# Eureka port in application.yml ignored

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I'm following this article (http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-netflix-eureka) to set up eureka, my application.yml looks like this

```
server:
    port: 8761
eureka:
    client:
        registerWithEureka: false
        fetchRegistry: false
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}
```

but I debug the main application I always get:

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.4.10.jar:1.4.10]
```

and when I got to my browser eureka is not in 8761 port but in 8080 port instead, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can't referece a property you just set above. This is not a procedural script, there's no guarantee the eureka line will be executed before the server one so ${server.port} will be the defaut: **8080**

If you run you app using an environment prop it will work. Try:

`java -Dserver.port=8761 -jar your-app.jar`

Comment: but I'm not starting any server, plus in the other examples I saw this problem seems not to exist

Comment: Replace `http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}` with this: `http://localhost:8761` or if the eureka server is not running on localhost, use the correct IP or dns .